# "Property Parameters cannot be empty" when creating a ClusterParameterGroup in Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK to deploy a Aurora RDS Cluster.

```
const cluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, 'id', {
      ...
      parameterGroup: new rds.ClusterParameterGroup(this,'id', { 
           family: 'aurora-postgresql11'
}})
```

Throws `Property Parameters cannot be empty` from the ClusterParameterGroup Construct. Any idea why?

When I try to use `ClusterParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, "id", [a group that I manually created in the account]` it works.

The reason I don't want to use the default ParameterGroup that RDS creates is because those are not modifiable. In case I need to modify them, I would need to create my own ParameterGroup resource.

Comment: I think that `ClusterParameterGroup` creates new group, thus at least one parameter should be provided. The `fromParameterGroupName` uses existing group.

Comment: true, but i'd like to inherit the default params there's at least 100 of them in the default config.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```js
    const rdsClusterPrameterGroup = ClusterParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(
      this,
      'rdsClusterPrameterGroup',
      'default.aurora-postgresql11',
    )
```

Then pass that to `DatabaseCluster` as `parameterGroup` value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName` does not create separate resource at all (just synthesize and look at the output), just name/reference to the default group.

Eventually seems like below code (python) does the thing. I needed to put one parameter to avoid `Property Parameters cannot be empty` error, thus the `application_name` which seems harmless. This is empty in defaults and stays empty in new group (among other unchanged defaults):

```
rds_db_param_group = rds.ParameterGroup(
    scope=self,
    id='CustomDbParams',
    engine=rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.aurora_postgres(
                version=rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_11_9
            ),
    description=f'custom-params-aurora-postgresql',
    parameters={
        'application_name' : '',
    }
)
```

And then pass `rds_db_param_group` to the DatabaseCluster and InstanceProps (as `parameter_group`):

```
rds.DatabaseCluster(self,
    instance_props=rds.InstanceProps(
        parameter_group=rds_db_param_group,
        [...]
    ),
    parameter_group=rds_db_param_group,
    [...]
)
```